# javascript - Convert multiple loop into one alert

Tags: javascript, php, loops, echo, alert

im using checkfile to upload file by **Month & Year** .

If success it will load the data to database.

```
IF checkfile = false
```

I want to display an **alert** message `("import Fail")`

```
foreach ($files1 as &$value) {

$checkfile = strpos($value,$input1 );

if($checkfile === false) {
//echo "<script>alert('Import Fail ');</script>";
}
else
{
echo "Import $value successfully! <br>" ;

     $query = "load data local infile '//192.168.100.3/Groups/$location1/Timesheet/$value'
                replace

      $result = $connection->query($query)  or exit("Error code ({$connection->errno}): {$connection->error}");

}

} 

unset($value);

?>
```

I tried to have echo **alert('Import Fail ');**

but it give me multiple alert every single file from the folder .

Comment: thats becaus its inside a foreach loop. it will give the error for each time it loops

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Way1 :** Manage the flow with flag as below. If any of the file successfully imported then change the flag and then make a condition on the flag to display alert.

```
$flag = 0;
foreach ($files1 as &$value) {

  $checkfile = strpos($value,$input1 );

  if($checkfile === false) {
    //echo "<script>alert('Import Fail ');</script>";
  }
  else
  {
    $flag = 1;
    echo "Import $value successfully! <br>" ;

     // $query1 = 
     // "Delete FROM hklcanet_pha.psr  this
     // WHERE year(psr.ReportDate) = $input3
     // AND month(psr.ReportDate) = $input2";


     $query = "load data local infile '//192.168.100.3/Groups/$location1/Timesheet/$value'
                replace
              into table hklcanet_pha.psr fields terminated by ','
              optionally enclosed by '\"'
              lines terminated by '\n'
              ignore 1 lines
               (`ReportDate`, @dummy, @dummy, `Team_refno`,`Name/Description`,`Status`,`PIC`,`RequestDate`,`TargetEndDate`,`ActualEndDate`,`PlanStartDate`,`ActualStartDate`,`PlanUATDate`,`ActualUATDate`,`PlanImplement`,`ActualImplement` )";

    //echo "Import $value successfully! <br>" ;


      $result = $connection->query($query)  or exit("Error code ({$connection->errno}): {$connection->error}");

  }

} 
if($flag == 1){
  echo "<script>alert('Import Fail ');</script>";
}
unset($value);

?>
```

**Way 2:** Get the name of successfully imported file names and make conditions on it.

```
$flag = [];
foreach ($files1 as &$value) {

  $checkfile = strpos($value,$input1 );

  if($checkfile === false) {    
    //echo "<script>alert('Import Fail ');</script>";
  }
  else
  {
    //Store successful file names in array
    $flag[] = $value;

     echo "Import $value successfully! <br>" ;

     // $query1 = 
     // "Delete FROM hklcanet_pha.psr  this
     // WHERE year(psr.ReportDate) = $input3
     // AND month(psr.ReportDate) = $input2";


     $query = "load data local infile '//192.168.100.3/Groups/$location1/Timesheet/$value'
                replace
              into table hklcanet_pha.psr fields terminated by ','
              optionally enclosed by '\"'
              lines terminated by '\n'
              ignore 1 lines
               (`ReportDate`, @dummy, @dummy, `Team_refno`,`Name/Description`,`Status`,`PIC`,`RequestDate`,`TargetEndDate`,`ActualEndDate`,`PlanStartDate`,`ActualStartDate`,`PlanUATDate`,`ActualUATDate`,`PlanImplement`,`ActualImplement` )";

    //echo "Import $value successfully! <br>" ;


      $result = $connection->query($query)  or exit("Error code ({$connection->errno}): {$connection->error}");

  }

} 
if(sizeof($flag) == 0){
  //Display all the file names in alert
  $failedFiles = implode(",",$flag);
  echo "<script>alert('Import Failed for files : ".$failedFiles."');</script>";
}
unset($value);

?>
```

Comment: It works!  but when the $checkfile  = true , it still have the alert message " import fail"

Comment: @beginner123 Have you tried way2? I have made change in it. If array size is greater then 0 then only import fail message will fire. Please check updated answer.

Comment: @beginner123 And for way1 if any file will fail then alert message with import fail will fired.

Comment: tried way 2, the succesful import still promp me "import Fail" 

I choose not to display the files because in the folder got too many files. 

removed .$failedFiles.

Comment: ya , was using the way 2  you suggest ( i removed the $failedFiles) 

when the import success ,  It still promp alert "Fail to import"

Comment: The prompt will only display if any of your file fails. As such if any of your file fails then only filename will be pushed in your array and then only the array size > 0 condition will satisfy and the prompt will display.

Comment: @ Rahul Patel what if I successfully import file (base by the Month / year)

Comment: @beginner123 not getting what you mean? But when you are print_r($failedFiles); Are you getting list of files which fails to import?

Comment: sorry. I am using Way 2. I getting the list of files which fails to import.

Comment: I dont want the the alert message "fail to import" when I success to import files.

Comment: Even if some of the files fails and some the file success you don't want to display the alert? Even if one out of all the file successfully imported you don't want to display failed alert message?

Comment: I have placed the flags in success condition in place of fail. So if a single file imported successfully from all the file alert will not appear and if all the files fails to import successfully alert will appear.

Comment: thank you for the update! I learned alot! it solved the problem!